# Compare data returned from $.getJSON to a String

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i have the following code:

```
$.getJSON('requestOnServer', {
    param1: value1,
    param2: 'value2'
}, function(result) {
    alert(result.attr.attr);
    if (result.attr.attr == "some String") {

        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
});​
```

The problem is that when i alert the returned string it shows correctly.
But when compare with == operator and even though the two strings are identical, It never return true in the first if statement.

So how do i compare the returned data with String correctly?

Comment: In your code, if you get the alert the condition in the if returned true.

Comment: Try console.logging the `result.attr.attr`, more than likely it has a space before or after it.

Comment: I'm confused, you have the alert within your if statement, and it fires, so how could it not be returning `true`?

Comment: sorry i have misplaced the alert statement while typing this code in here

Comment: @Kevin B if he sent back the data as JSON and it had a whitspace, wouldn't alerting it provide a malformed object error because it's invalid?

Comment: not if that whitespace is part of the string stored in result.attr.attr

Comment: @Kevin B ah...you're saying `"param":" some String"`

Comment: Solved it turns out i am returning a Boolean not String ...LOL ..Thank you all though

Answer (score 0):

first you need to identify the typeof result.attr.attr,
in case that this is a string (or any other type) log it out using console.log() or use alert() and add some characters at start and end of it something like alert("======"+result.attr.attr+"======"); this is the simple way to approve that you don't have a space before and after as @Kevin B write.